# @media min-height doesn't work

Tags: css, media-queries

I try to use @media to check height of browser if it less than 600px

I want to set a new max-width and height so what did I do wrong?

or any missing syntax ?? Please advice and help , Thank!

I also have other @media which is work but for height not.

```
   @media only screen and (min-height: 600px){
        #book-container{
            max-width: 748px;
            max-height: 469px;
        }
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
    #txt-search{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}

#book-container{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 830px;
    max-height: 520px;

    /*max-width: 748px;*/
    /*max-height: 469px;*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@media only screen and (min-height: 600px)` applies for screen widths of *over* 600 pixels. Generally, you want `max-*`:

```
@media only screen and (max-height: 600px) {
    …
}
```

Comment: "Generally, you want max" - not in mobile-first design.

Comment: @Pavlo: Generally, people don’t want mobile-first design. i.e. most of the time on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @minitech That's controversial. Any data to prove this point?

Comment: @Pavlo: No, it’s not controversial, and sure, search Stack Overflow for the number of instances of `(min-width` as compared to `(max-width`. `(max-width` is the most common; most questions about `(min-width` are mistaking it for `(max-width`. But let’s please not dwell on it, because it is really irrelevant.

Comment: @JongzPuangput: Can you set up [an example](http://codepen.io/pen) to demonstrate the problem? [(It works for me.)](http://codepen.io/minitech/pen/pyGIv)